# Selected picklist item label

Tags: picklist

I would like to get label of stored picklist value. Is there any straight forward way of doing that or I have to loop through all picklist values?

Comment: I suspect you will have to loop through to get it. Might be an idea to store the label on a hidden field to save yourself repeated processing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For picklist values you can use the toLabel() function in soql to retreive the label, e.g.

```
select select id,name, toLabel(Industry) from account
```

Otherwise you can call describeSobject and get the label from the returned picklistValue structure.

Answer (score 0):

You may Use Custom settings to store the Labels if you think looping may bring issues.Have a custom Setting with api name and label and you may use custom setting methods to retrieve only for those you want.

```
Map mapCodes = ISO_Country__c.getAll();
// display the ISO code for Afghanistan
System.debug(‘ISO Code: ‘+mapCodes.get(‘AFGHANISTAN’).ISO_Code__c);
```

Comment: The "custom setting approach" screw you up so hard as soon as a requirement to get the translated labels will pop up ;) Cust. Labels would be better...

Comment: Ah great point !!Yes if multilingual custom labels are preferred